# how to fix this in bootstrap 5 nav bar dropdown stays open with click and mouse over

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 5 and enabled dropdown on click and hover.

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
        display: block;
        border-style:none;
        }
```

The problem is after I click on the top level dropdown item (that displays the dropdown items) and when I mouse over to next item the previous dropdown window stays open. How can I avoid this?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A third link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A third link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since it opens on mouse over, you don't need it on click. Remove `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` from the dropdown and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. However, I suspect this will create issues on mobile - is there any way to disable this except for mobile?

Comment: There shouldn't be much of a problem as either on hover or click, you expect the same behavior. But if you still really want to keep it separate, you can use media query for the hover effect to apply only on larger screens and control the toggle attribute via js.